# Ruby default value for def

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby method:

```
def get(name1="john", age=31)
    puts "#{name1} + #{age}"
end
```

How can I allocate only a variable "age"?
For example:

```
    get(:age => 3)
    => john + 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close:

```
def get(name1: "john", age: 31)
    puts "#{name1} + #{age}"
end

get(:age => 3) # => john + 3
```

Answer (score 4):

When Ruby encounters

```
def m(a=1, b=2, c=3)
  puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{3}"
end
```

This is what happens:

```
m(4,5)
  # a=4, b=5, c=3
```

Ruby has no way of knowing which variable you want assigned to its default so she employs a simple rule: assign arguments to variables left to right until they are used up, then any remaining arguments are assigned to their default values.

If you want a different priority you could change the order of the arguments, say,

```
def m(b=2, c=3, a=1)
  puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{3}"
end

m(4,5)
  # a=1, b=4, c=3
```

This may suffice in some situations but a more flexible solution, which also reads better, is to use *named arguments* (aka *named paramters*), as @steenstag has done in his solution. Here that might be as follows.

```
def m(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
  d = a + c
  puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{c}, d=#{d}"
end

m(:b=>4, :c=>5)
  # a=1, b=4, c=5, d=6
m(c: 4)
  # a=1, b=2, c=4, d=5
```

Notice that I've written `c=>5` in the first instance and `c: 4` in the second. Either form can be used. We cannot, however, write `def m(:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3)`.

Since Ruby v2.1 we can also have *required* named arguments:

```
def m(a:, b: 2, c: 3)
  puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{c}"
end

m(c:5, a: 4)
  # a=4, b=2, c=5
m(c: 5)
  # ArgumentError (missing keyword: a)
```

We can also have some named and some unnamed arguments, provided the named arguments are at the end, but its less confusing to simply name all arguments if any are named.

```
def m(d, a:, b: 2, c: 3)
  puts "d=#{d}, a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{c}"
end

m(6, c:5, a: 4)
  # d=6, a=4, b=2, c=5

def m(a:, b: 2, c: 3, d)
end
  #=> SyntaxError ((irb):165: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER)
  #   ... def m(a:, b: 2, c: 3, d)
  #                             ^
```